# how to use object proxy in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

hi here is some code that i have to read & understood so can anybody explain me what 
  object proxy does and whats benefit because just formatting it?

```
  override public function set currentResult(value:ArrayCollection):void
    {
        super.currentResult = value;
        dispatch(new doEvent(getFormatData(value)));
    }

    private static function getFormat(ddList:ArrayCollection):ArrayCollection
    {
        var formattedArr:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
        for each(var obj:Object in ddList)
            formattedArr.addItem(new ObjectProxy(obj));

        return formattedArr;
    }
```

Comment: this all hapening in a robort legs model

Comment: add more  code to explain what do u exactly want?

Answer (score 3):

ObjectProxy provides the ability to track changes to an item managed by this proxy. Any number of objects can "listen" for changes on this object, by using the addEventListener() method.use  [this](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/09/27/detecting-changes-to-an-object-using-the-flex-objectproxy-class/)  to more clear.

Comment: i m new in industry can u plz explain when i debug the current result in above code ...i got 7 columns..but now when i am trying to debug formattedAddr it gives back 8 column in a single array while ...how its work can u explain little bit?